# Service can't read certificate store

Tags: c#, service, permissions, certificate, x509

We want to create a service that would automatically delete certificates from the store (using c#). When we run the .exe by hand everything goes smoothly. But when we create a service from that .exe it doesn't read the certificates in the store and keeps saying that it's empty.

What can we do to correct that?

Here is the part that reads the store and then deletes all the found certificates:

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
X509Certificate2Collection storecollection = (X509Certificate2Collection)store.Certificates;
foreach (X509Certificate2 x509 in storecollection)
{
    store.Remove(x509);
}
store.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is reading the store correctly. Problem is that your service (when installed) runs under different user. And his certificate store is empty.
When you run the service by double clicking on .exe it runs under your account.

You could set the service to run under your account if you wish. You do that in service properties on Log On tab.

Comment: Thank you for that info.

We did as you suggested but the service crashed as soon as we started it. Does the fact that the account we're using is a domain account somehow couse this?
Otherwise we compile the code, install and run the service all under one account - which store is then beign read if not of the current user?

Comment: Domain account should not have such effect on the service. I have run services under domain accounts many times before. Where did it crash. Do you have logs of what happened? Did you input username like `domain\username` when you configured credentials for the service? Did you give right password?

Comment: It crashed right at the beginning before actually doing anything. The username and password were definitely correct, it didn't accept wrong ones. As for the log we'll try to get it. Is there any way to get the name of the store and then call it by name?

Comment: Like this `X509Store store = new X509Store ("My", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);` ?

Comment: In this case we get the initial problem where it says the store is empty, so it's not looking at the correct store. Is there any other way to pinpoint one specific store?

Comment: None that I know of. What about those logs? Did event log mention something? You might also try to call `Debugger.Break()` from `OnStart` method of the service. Or you could add `Thread.Sleep(10000)` in OnStart method to be able to attach to it from visual studio in time.